# Ruby rest-client params with json (and quotes)

Tags: ruby, rest-client

This works (on ubuntu):

```
curl -v -g 'https://example.com/api/path/to/service?json={"select":["cats","dogs","cows"],"from":"20170115","to":"20170117"}'
```

And this works too (in ruby):

```
require 'rest-client'

resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
    'https://example.com/api/path/to/service?json={"select":["cats","dogs","cows"],"from":"20170115","to":"20170117"}')
resp = resource.get
```

**However, I would like to split request host and body (in ruby).**

I tried this:

```
require 'rest-client'

resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
        'https://example.com/api/path/to/service')
resp = resource.get(:data => 'json={"select":["cats","dogs","cows"],"from":"20170115","to":"20170117"}', :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

but the server returns:

```
# => 400 BadRequest | application/json 49 bytes
No such encoding: "utf8"
```

and also with this variation:

```
resp = resource.get(:json => '{"select":["cats","dogs","cows"],"from":"20170115","to":"20170117"}', :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

and equivalent with `:payload =>` but got same error result.

I have looked stackoverflow thin but nothing I tried seems to work. I have a feeling it is something with the way ruby is escaping the double quotes before sending - just a guess.

Any ideas?

All help would be greatly appreciated. Even a link to the right stackoverflow answer :-)

Thanks.